# Changing only first to second in printf in C

Tags: c, printf

Consider any C program on array. I want to print it's output. Outputs will be like "The first element is `%d\n` The second element is `%d` and so on.

I don't want to write these statements as there can be many elements in an array and I would have to keep on writing this until the end.

**So, is there an easy method using loops or something which can automatically change only the letters first to second and second to third in the `printf` statements and print accordingly?**

You can use any thing in C like strings and all.

Comment: "avoid pointers", in C, wow.

Comment: You could write a set of arrays containing strings like `first, second, third,...,eighteenth, nineteenth, twentieth, twenty-, thirtieth, thirty-` etc., then loop through these arrays and choose the appropriate replacement as `The %s element is %d\n`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
   printf("The element at index %i is %d\n", i, array[i]);
}
```

If you need the index as a text, you will need an array of strings to convert the numerical value to the string value (1 => first, 2 => second etc.)

Comment: I got it. Thank you. I had said no pointers because I still haven't learnt it. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you are going to get is something like:

```
char *arr[] = {
"first",
"second",
"third",
"fourth",
...
};

for (i = 0; i < something; i ++)
{
    printf("the %s element is %d\n", arr[i], other_arr[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
for(a=0;a<=number_of_elements;a++)
{
    printf("the %d indexed element is %c",a,array[a]);
}
```

**Use the ^ loop and try.I hope that it will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind "1th, 2th, 3th" etc...

```
printf("the %dth element is %d\n", i + 1, array[i]);
```